# AppDelegate methods not called when using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)

Tags: ios, firebase, appdelegate, ios13

Since I installed Firebase with FCM for notifications, most of my appDelegate methods aren't called anymore (except `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:  `applicationDidEnterBackground` or `applicationDidBecomeActive` for example.
Is there something else to do to retrieve the AppDelegate normal behavior? Thanks!

```swift
import UIKit
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

// Still called, app launches UI normally.
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
         FirebaseOptions.defaultOptions()?.deepLinkURLScheme = Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier
        FirebaseApp.configure()        
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
        Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
          options: authOptions,
          completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        self.window?.rootViewController = LoadingViewController.instantiate()
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true 
    }

// Not called anymore 
    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        log.verbose("applicationWillResignActive") 
    }

// Not called anymore   
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        log.verbose("applicationDidEnterBackground")
        RideController.shared.prepareForBackground() 
    }

// Not called anymore  
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        log.verbose("applicationWillEnterForeground") 
    }

// Not called anymore
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        log.verbose("applicationDidBecomeActive")
        RideController.shared.prepareForForeground() // Not called anymore
        // Watch
        WatchController.shared.startSession() 
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        log.verbose("applicationWillTerminate")
        RideController.shared.prepareForBackground()
    }

}

/ MARK: - UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate methods
extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Swift.Void) {
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(notification.request.content.userInfo)
    }


// MARK: - MessagingDelegate methods
extension AppDelegate: MessagingDelegate {

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        log.info("FCM registration token received = \(fcmToken)")
        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        log.info("didReceive message = \(remoteMessage)")
    }
}
```

Comment: link your app delegate

Comment: if you're using storyboards and not setting the window property etc, then it won't work, you need to use the window property in the app delegate and more to make this work.

Comment: The app still launches, UI works fine, just the other lifecycle methods aren't called anymore...

Comment: so i see, yeah, you've set it up correctly, that's really weird

Answer (score 1):

Wow! I found the bug. I use the Pod Firebase in my app and apparently Firebase Cloud Messaging service (FCM) swizzles the app delegate at launch. I had to put this key `FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` to NO in my info.plist file to fix it.

Comment: Hi @matt, thank you for your feedbacks, Sorry for my beginner's mistakes but I understand better now! I edited my post to mention Firebase, is that better now?